# Measuring duration of ultra-short laser pulses

Tags: laser, measurements

I read that the duration of one ultra-short laser pulse in a pulse train can be measured with autocorrelators or more sophisticated methods like Frequency-Resolved Optical Gating (FROG).

In principle one could simply measure the spectral width using a spectrometer and correlate it to the time width of the single pulse. Why is this approach not enough and there is need to use other methods?

Answer (score 1):

A spectrometer gives the amplitude of each Fourier coefficient, but not the phase. Phase matters. In the most extreme example, if you add all frequencies with the right phase, you get a delta function. The same sum with random phase gives white noise.

Comment: But I'm interested in the duration of a single pulse. This duration increases when the spectral width decreases and vice-versa. Is the phase among the spectral components needed to measure the pulse duration?

Comment: Yes. A delta function is the ultimate single pulse.

Comment: An intensity autocorrelator works as explained here https://www.rp-photonics.com/autocorrelators.html. In which way it uses the phases of the Fourier components?

Comment: It doesn't. It works in the time domain, not the frequency domain. Loosely, it compares pulse intensity at two times with various delays between them. If both times have a high intensity, the time delay is shorter than the pulse width. The article has a link to [Fourier Transform Spectroscopy](https://www.rp-photonics.com/fourier_transform_spectroscopy.html), which is a separate topic. You would likely get better results from an autocorrelator than from trying to calculate pulse width from the Fourier Transform.